# eclipse web browser (ie?) vs. firefox -> word wrapping inconsistent

Tags: string, internet-explorer, jsf, firefox, seam

I'm having inconsistent behaviour betweeen IE and Firefox.  I would like the outputText to wrap within it's own cell.  IE does this perfectly, but Firefox has it entering itself on a line below.  I've tried to use the word-wrap CSS property, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Code:

```
<s:decorate>
   <ui:param name="labelWidth" value="130px" />
   <ui:define name="label">Summary:</ui:define>
   <h:outputText value="#{myView.myBean.summary}" style="word-wrap: normal"/>
</s:decorate>
```

Firefox:

[image]

```
<div id="j_id55">
  <div id="j_id55:j_id56" class="prop">
    <span id="j_id55:j_id57" class="name" style="width: 130px">Summary:</span>
      <span id="j_id55:j_id59" class="value">Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

IE:

[image]

```
<div id="j_id55">
  <div id="j_id55:j_id56" class="prop">
     <span id="j_id55:j_id57" class="name" style="width: 130px">Summary:</span>
     <span id="j_id55:j_id59" class="value">
       <span style="word-wrap: normal">Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long
       </span>
     </span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Since Seam (that's where the `s:` prefix comes from, right?) is a decaying knowledge, can you post the generated html part so the IE and Firefox subscribers can give you input, too?

Comment: @mabi source has been added in